# How to add google drive in your finder like dropbox and iCloud drive

Tags: icloud

How can I add google drive in my finder menu so that I can directly share data to cloud like we do in Dropbox or iCloud ?

Answer (score 0):

Download & Install from here: https://www.google.com/drive/download/

Your sync folder will be located at `~/Google Drive` and will be automatically put in the side par of Finder.